# call out consecutive rows from different dataframes

Tags: r, loops, lapply

I have imported 60 dataframes in a list. Each of these dfs have 67500 rows and look like this:

```
$B00300.dat
           ZONE    T..Frame      X0..    I.300.   
1     -152.727318   75.200516  0.000000  0.000000    
2     -150.659950   75.200516  0.000000  0.000000    
3     -148.592582   75.200516  0.000000  0.000000    
4     -146.525213   75.200516  0.000000  0.000000    
5     -144.457845   75.200516  0.000000  0.000000    
6     -142.390477   75.200516  0.000000  0.000000    
7     -140.323109   75.200516  0.000000  0.000000    
8     -138.255741   75.200516  0.000000  0.000000
```

I have been able to call out one specific row (by specifying the values) from all the 60 dataframes using this script:

```
list.filenames <- list.files(path = "D:/data")
list.filenames
list.data <- list()
for(i in 1:length(list.filenames)) {
    list.data[[i]] <- read.delim(list.filenames[I], header = TRUE, 
                                 sep = "", skip = 2)
}
names(list.data) <- list.filenames
list.data[1]

lapply(list.data, function(x) {
  filter(x,ZONE==399.259947, T..Frame==-150.142600)
})
```

now i want to systematically call out nth row from the 1st dataframe, (n-1)th row from the 2nd dataframe....(n-34)th frame from the 35th df and so on. How can i do this in a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try doing something like this:

```
# Your list of dataframes
myList  <- list(mtcars, mtcars, mtcars)
# nth row to call
startAt <- 3

t(sapply(1:length(myList), function(x) myList[[x]][startAt - x + 1, ]))
```

`1:length(myList)` goes from `1` to `3`.
When `x == 1` it gets first dataframe (`myList[[1]]`) and extracts nth row from it (`[3 - 1 + 1, ]`).
When `x == 2` it gets second dataframe (`myList[[2]]`) and extracts nth - 1 row from it (`[3 - 2 + 1, ]`).